# How to change figuresize using seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
%pylab inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

typessns = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('C:/data/testesns.csv', index_col=False, sep=';')

mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(45, 10))
sns.factorplot("MONTH", "VALUE", hue="REGION", data=typessns, kind="box", palette="OrRd");
```

[image]

I always get a small size figure, no matter what size I 've specified in figsize...
How to fix it?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

> Note added in 2019: In modern seaborn versions the `size` argument has been renamed to `height`.

To be a little more concrete:

```
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns

exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# Defaults are size=5, aspect=1
sns.factorplot("kind", "pulse", "diet", exercise, kind="point", size=2, aspect=1)
sns.factorplot("kind", "pulse", "diet", exercise, kind="point", size=4, aspect=1)
sns.factorplot("kind", "pulse", "diet", exercise, kind="point", size=4, aspect=2)
```

You want to pass in the arguments 'size' or 'aspect' to the sns.factorplot() when constructing your plot.

**Size** will change the height, *while maintaining the aspect ratio* (so it will also also get wider if only size is changed.)

**Aspect** will change the width while keeping the height constant.

The above code should be able to be run locally in an ipython notebook.

*Plot sizes are reduced in these examples to show the effects, and because the plots from the above code were fairly large when saved as png's. This also shows that size/aspect includes the legend in the margin.*

**size=2, aspect=1**

[image: size=2, aspect=1]

**size=4, aspect=1**

[image: size=4, aspect=1]

**size=4, aspect=2**

[image: size=4, aspect=2]

Also, all other useful parameters/arguments and defaults for this plotting function can be viewed with once the 'sns' module is loaded:

```
help(sns.factorplot)
```

Comment: this is the only solution that works for me. Tried all the others,  even when there are no errors, the figure still displays as default size and aspect (small and square).

Answer (score 24):

`mpl.rc` is stored in a global dictionary (see http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).
So, if you only want to change the size of one figure (locally), it will do the trick:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(45,10))
sns.factorplot(...)
```

It worked for me using `matplotlib-1.4.3` and `seaborn-0.5.1`

Comment: Did work for me until I respected same order than you, `plt.figure` must indeed go first. Thanks

Comment: In which case, you also need `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: @psychemedia I also found it better to stick with 'height' param instead of importing pyplot for most cases!

Answer (score 5):

The size of the figure is controlled by the `size` and `aspect` arguments to `factorplot`. They correspond to the size of each *facet* ("`size`" really means "height" and then `size * aspect` gives the width), so if you are aiming for a particularl size for the whole figure you'll need to work backwards from there.

Comment: My first day of using matplotlib and Seaborn, so apologies for the stupid question, but what is `mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(45, 10))` good for, then, if not controlling the size of the figure? I also see the same `mpl.rc` code used here: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/112 — and it doesn't change the size in my plots.

Answer (score 5):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(12.7,8.6)})

plt.figure(figsize=(45,10))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO7ms.png)

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not use `%pylab inline`, it is deprecated, use `%matplotlib inline`
2. The question is not specific to IPython.
3. use seaborn `.set_style` function, pass it your rc as second parameter or kwarg.: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.set_style.html

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to scale the figure use the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.factorplot("MONTH", "VALUE", hue="REGION", data=typessns, kind="box", palette="OrRd"); // OR any plot code
```

Answer (score 3):

Note as of July 2018:

`seaborn.__version__ == 0.9.0`

**Two main changes which affect the above answers**

1. The `factorplot` function has been renamed to [`catplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot)
2. The `size` parameter has been renamed to `height` for multi plot grid functions and those that use them.

> https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html

Meaning the answer provided by *@Fernando Hernandez* should be adjusted as per below:

```
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns

exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# Defaults are hieght=5, aspect=1
sns.catplot("kind", "pulse", "diet", exercise, kind="point", height=4, aspect=2)
```