# Move seaborn plot legend to a different position

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I'm using `factorplot(kind="bar")` with seaborn.

The plot is fine except the legend is misplaced: too much to the right, text goes out of the plot's shaded area.

How do I make seaborn place the legend somewhere else, such as in top-left instead of middle-right?

Comment: For `seaborn >= 0.11.2` use `.move_legend` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849891/7758804)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Building on @user308827's answer: you can use `legend=False` in factorplot and specify the legend through matplotlib:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.factorplot("class", "survived", "sex",
                   data=titanic, kind="bar",
                   size=6, palette="muted",
                   legend=False)
g.despine(left=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
g.set_ylabels("survival probability")
```

- `plt` acts on the current axes. To get axes from a `FacetGrid` use fig.

  - `g.fig.get_axes()[0].legend(loc='lower left')`

Comment: This generally does not work for seaborn plots.

Answer (score 52):

- For [`seaborn >= 0.11.2`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html#v0-11-2-august-2021) use [`seaborn.move_legend`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html), which applies to [Axes and Figure level plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions), and it accepts `kwargs`, like `title`

  - See [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) and [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804) for parameters and their usage.
- The original question asked about `sns.factorplot`, which has been renamed to [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html), a figure-level plot.
- For `g = sns.jointplot` or `g = sns.JointGrid`, the legend is in `g.ax_joint`, not `g`.

  - `sns.move_legend(g.ax_joint)`
  - See [How to move or remove the legend from a seaborn JointGrid or jointplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73226708/7758804).
- `.move_legend` is for moving the legend, not changing the legend title, or labels. This should be done by cleaning the data.

  - In `pandas`, there are various ways to change column names and the string values in a column, such as [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html), and [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.5.0`, `matplotlib 3.5.2`, `seaborn 0.12.0`**

  - See [How can I customize the legend with Seaborn 0.12 objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73633322/7758804) to relocate legends using the new [`seaborn.object`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.12.0.html#introduction-of-the-objects-interface) interface, which debuted in `seaborn 0.12.0`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# load the data
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins', cache=False)
```

### Figure Level Plot

```py
g = sns.displot(penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species", col="island", col_wrap=2, height=3)
sns.move_legend(g, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(.55, .45), title='Species')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Axes Level Plot

```py
ax = sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species")
sns.move_legend(ax, "lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(.5, 1), ncol=3, title=None, frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Modifying the example [here](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/factorplot_bars.html):

You can use `legend_out = False`

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.factorplot("class", "survived", "sex",
                    data=titanic, kind="bar",
                    size=6, palette="muted",
                   legend_out=False)
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("survival probability")
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Check out the docs here: https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-location

adding this simply worked to bring legend out of the plot:

`plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)`

Comment: This generally does not work with seaborn generated figures.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I was able to move the legend to a particular place inside the plot and change the aspect and size of the plot:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")

figure_name = 'rater_violinplot.png'
figure_output_path = output_path + figure_name

viol_plot = sns.factorplot(x="Rater", 
                       y="Confidence", 
                       hue="Event Type", 
                       data=combo_df, 
                       palette="colorblind",
                       kind='violin',
                       size = 10,
                       aspect = 1.5,
                       legend=False)

viol_plot.ax.legend(loc=2)
viol_plot.fig.savefig(figure_output_path)
```

[image: Legend location changed]

This worked for me to change the size and aspect of the plot as well as move the legend outside the plot area.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")


figure_name = 'rater_violinplot.png'
figure_output_path = output_path + figure_name

viol_plot = sns.factorplot(x="Rater", 
                       y="Confidence", 
                       hue="Event Type", 
                       data=combo_df, 
                       palette="colorblind",
                       kind='violin',
                       size = 10,
                       aspect = 1.5,
                       legend_out=True)

viol_plot.fig.savefig(figure_output_path)
```

[image: violin plot with changed size, aspect and legend located outside]

I figured this out from mwaskom's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface) and Fernando Hernandez's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163702/how-to-change-figuresize-using-seaborn-factorplot).

Answer (score 4):

it seems you can directly call:

```
g = sns.factorplot("class", "survived", "sex",
                data=titanic, kind="bar",
                size=6, palette="muted",
               legend_out=False)

g._legend.set_bbox_to_anchor((.7, 1.1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to customize your legend, just use the `add_legend` method. It takes the same parameters as matplotlib `plt.legend`.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.factorplot("class", "survived", "sex",
                    data=titanic, kind="bar",
                    size=6, palette="muted",
                   legend_out=False)
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("survival probability")
g.add_legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

Comment: it seems this creates a new legend. In my code, I have other lines to adjust the legend (title, size, and transparency ..). If I call this to adjust the position, the following lines don't work then...

Answer (score 0):

Using object oriented API:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.someplot(...,ax=ax)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels,loc="upper left")
```

source: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

Comment: This does not work with current versions of seaborn. [Figure-level plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gbNT.png) result in an error, and [axes-level plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyVzA.png) don't result in an error, but the legend does not appear. The correct option is `seaborn.move_legend`

Comment: I just modified my answer. If you pass ax to the argument then it should work just fine.