# Move legend outside figure in seaborn tsplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create a time series plot using `seaborn.tsplot` like in [this example from `tsplot` documentation](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn-dev/examples/timeseries_from_dataframe.html), but with the legend moved to the right, outside the figure.

[image: example]

Based on the lines 339-340 in [seaborn's timeseries.py](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/timeseries.py), it looks like `seaborn.tsplot` currently doesn't allow direct control of legend placement:

```
    if legend:
        ax.legend(loc=0, title=legend_name)
```

Is there a matplotlib workaround?
I'm using seaborn 0.6-dev.

Comment: For `seaborn >= 0.11.2` use `sns.move_legend` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849891/7758804) (answered Aug 19, 2021) of the duplicate.

Answer (score 211):

### 20220916 Update

Since version v0.11.2 of `seaborn`, there is an in-built control of the legend position, see [seaborn.move_legend](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html). To put the legend outside:

```py
ax = sns.histplot(penguins, x="bill_length_mm", hue="species")
sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image]

### Old Answer

Indeed, `seaborn` doesn't handle legends well so far. You can use `plt.legend()` to control legend properties directly through `matplotlib`, in accordance with [Matplotlib Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).

Note that in Seaborn 0.10.0 `tsplot` was removed, and you may replicate (with different values for the estimation if you please) the plots with `lineplot` instead of `tsplot`.

#### Snippet

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

# Load the long-form example gammas dataset
gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")

# Plot the response with standard error
sns.lineplot(data=gammas, x="timepoint", y="BOLD signal", hue="ROI")

# Put the legend out of the figure
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

#### Output

[image: Modified legend position]

Comment: `g = sns.plot...; sns.move_legend(g, 'center left', bbox_to_anchor=[1, .5])`
[`sns.move_legend`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html)

Comment: `sns.move_legend` duplicates the answer that's already in the close duplicate.

Answer (score 29):

Existing solutions seem to be making things unnecessarily complicated by using the "wrong" thing for the location parameter; think about it terms of where the legend is in relation to an anchor.  For example, if you want a legend on the right, then the anchor location is `center left` of it.

We can simplify Sergey Antopolskiy's answer down to:

```
import seaborn as sns

# Load the long-form example gammas dataset
g = sns.lineplot(data=gammas, x="timepoint", y="BOLD signal", hue="ROI")

# Put the legend out of the figure
g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

`bbox_to_anchor` says we want the anchor on the right (i.e. `1` on the x-axis) and vertically centered (`0.5` on the y-axis).  `loc` says we want the legend center-left of this anchor.

In Seaborn version 0.11.0, this gives me something like:

[image: tidy example]

Comment: This gives me a `'Legend' object is not callable` error (seaborn 0.11.2)

Comment: @emilaz think you must be doing something else, it works for me with 0.11.2

Comment: Yeah I was doing this for a seaborn pairplot, that might be the reason :)

Answer (score 20):

I tried to apply T.W.'s answer for **seaborn lineplot**, without success. A few modifications to his answer did the job... in case anyone is looking for the lineplot version as I was!

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset("gammas")

# EDIT: I Needed to ad the fig
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

# EDIT: 
# T.W.' answer said: "create with hue but without legend" <- # I needed to include it!
# So, removed: legend=False
g = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="BOLD signal", hue="ROI", data=df, ax=ax1) 

# EDIT: 
# Removed 'ax' from T.W.'s answer here aswell:
box = g.get_position()
g.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.85, box.height]) # resize position

# Put a legend to the right side
g.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.5), ncol=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: Seaborn Lineplot with Legend outside]

Comment: If you call `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()`, you don't need to move the plot. Also, `g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 0.5), ncol=1)` would put the legend at the right, with its left center anchored.

Answer (score 7):

The answer by Sergey worked great for me using a `seaborn.tsplot` but I was not able to get it working for an `seaborn.lmplot` so I looked a bit deeper and found another solution:

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# load data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('mydata.csv')

# create with hue but without legend
g = sns.lmplot(x="x_data", y="y_data", hue="condition", legend=False, data=df)

# resize figure box to -> put the legend out of the figure
box = g.ax.get_position() # get position of figure
g.ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.85, box.height]) # resize position

# Put a legend to the right side
g.ax.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.5), ncol=1)

sns.plt.show(g)
```

Maybe you have to play around with the values to fit them to your legend.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/) answer will also be helpful if you need more examples.

Answer (score 6):

### A pure `seaborn` solution:

`FacetGrid`-based Seaborn plots can do this automatically using the `legend_out` kwarg. Using `relplot`, pass `legend_out` to the `FacetGrid` constructor via the `facet_kws` dictionary:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")

sns.relplot(
    data=gammas,
    x="timepoint",
    y="BOLD signal",
    hue="ROI",
    kind="line",
    facet_kws={"legend_out": True}
)
```

[image: Example plot with legend placement outside using FacetGrid.]

Comment: For some reason `facet_out=True` has no effect using `seaborn 0.11.1`.

Comment: legend_out, not facet_out

Comment: I mean `legend_out`.Using seaborn 0.11.1 and matplotlib 3.3.4.