# Getting error: No handles with labels found to put in legend. when moving legend outside of the box when plotting with kdeplot with searborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am plotting a kde plot using the seaborn kdeplot.

```
time_window_order=['272','268','264','260','256','252','248','244','240']
order_dict = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(time_window_order)}
df =DataFrame ({'time_window':['268','268','268','264','252','252','252','240',
                               '256','256','256','256','252','252','252','240'],
                'seq_no':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
                          'b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b']})
df['centre_point'] = df['time_window'].map(order_dict)

g =sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="centre_point",hue='seq_no', bw_adjust=0.8);plt.xlim(0,len(time_window_order)-1);plt.grid()
g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5)) # move legend outside the box
plt.xticks(ticks = range(0,len(time_window_order)) ,labels = time_window_order, rotation = 'vertical')
plt.show()
```

I tried reposition the `legend` outside the box using the line `g.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))` [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64573338/6446053).

Instead, the compiler return an error

> No handles with labels found to put in legend.

Also, instead of complete legend, the legend appear to become like a small rectangle as shown by the red arrow, in the figure below.
[image]

May I know how to fix this?

Comment: You can try (1.25, 0.5) rather than (1, 0.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn does not handle legends well; you can use this workaround:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_window_order=['272','268','264','260','256','252','248','244','240']
order_dict = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(time_window_order)}
df = pd.DataFrame ({'time_window': ['268','268','268','264','252','252','252','240',
                                    '256','256','256','256','252','252','252','240'],
                    'seq_no': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
                               'b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b']})
df['centre_point'] = df['time_window'].map(order_dict)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, hue="seq_no", height=6, aspect=1.5)
g = (g.map(sns.kdeplot, "centre_point", bw_adjust=0.8))

plt.xlim(0, len(time_window_order)-1)
plt.ylabel('density')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 0.5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks(ticks=range(0, len(time_window_order)), labels=time_window_order, rotation='vertical')
plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: KDE Plot]

Comment: Thanks David, but I think this way around might have issue when one would like to append another ax on top of the other.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Say for example: `ax=sns.kdeplot(data=df0, x="centre_point",hue='feature', bw_adjust=0.5)
ax=sns.kdeplot(data=df1, x="centre_point",hue='feature', bw_adjust=0.5,ax=ax)` Usually, one will pass the `ax` onto the second handle to get multiple kde in a single plot. I will make a sample data and perhaps post new OP to better explain about this