# How to do Scatter Plot column wise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plot, scatter

This is my entire dataframe.

[image].

I want  a 2d scatter plot based on column '0' and '1' according to column `class` wise. There are all total 32 classes. So in my plot there will be 32 unique colors.

---

As an example , If i plot this,

[image]

the plot should consist of 8 points whose co-ordinates are (0.038556,-0.011442),(0.051171,0.009094) so on so forth. And there are three classes 1) travel 2) politics, 3) sports so three unique color will be used as label.

How to plot this entire data frame like this using python?

---

**EDIT**

[image]

Thanks for this code. but how to edit that red marked portion, it covers the actual plot so nothing is visible.

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.scatterplot(x='0',y='1',hue='Class', data=df)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for your help! Can u please help me with the problem now I am facing

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490740/move-legend-outside-figure-in-seaborn-tsplot)