# add legend seaborn barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, legend

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.array([[1,5,9],[3,5,7]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=['Positive', 'Negative'])

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

current_palette = sns.color_palette('colorblind')

ax_pos = sns.barplot(x = np.arange(0,3,1), y = df.loc['Positive'].to_numpy(), color = current_palette[2], alpha = 0.66)
ax_neg = sns.barplot(x = np.arange(0,3,1), y = df.loc['Negative'].to_numpy(), color = current_palette[4], alpha = 0.66)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,3,1), fontsize = 20)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10,1), fontsize = 20)

plt.legend((ax_pos[0], ax_neg[0]), ('Positive', 'Negative'))

plt.tight_layout()
```

Which produces the follow error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 15
     12 plt.xticks(np.arange(0,3,1), fontsize = 20)
     13 plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10,1), fontsize = 20)
---> 15 plt.legend((ax_pos[0], ax_neg[0]), ('Positive', 'Negative'))
     17 plt.tight_layout()

TypeError: 'Axes' object is not subscriptable
```

[image]

I would like to know why calling legend like this (plt.legend(ax[0]...) is not possible with seaborn, whereas with matplotlib it is.

In the end, I just want the legend in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that barplot has "label" function :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = np.array([[1,5,9],[3,5,7]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=['Positive', 'Negative'])

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

current_palette = sns.color_palette('colorblind')

sns.barplot(x = np.arange(0,3,1), y = df.loc['Positive'].to_numpy(), color = current_palette[2], alpha = 0.66, label = "Positive")
sns.barplot(x = np.arange(0,3,1), y = df.loc['Negative'].to_numpy(), color = current_palette[4], alpha = 0.66, label = "Negative")

plt.xticks(np.arange(0,3,1), fontsize = 20)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10,1), fontsize = 20)

plt.legend(frameon = False)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- The bar plot in the OP, and the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61254601/7758804), is wrong. The bars are layered in the z-order, not stacked, which is non-standard, and likely to be misinterpreted. As shown in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tD83.png).
- The correct way to plot a wide dataframe, with labeled index values, is with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

  - The values in the `index` will be the `xticklabels`, and the `column` names will be the legend labels.
  - Depending on how the data should be presented, use [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to transpose the `index` and `columns`.
- In general, stacked bars are not the best way to present data because, beyond two groups, it's difficult to accurately compare the lengths.

  - Grouped bars are better because the bar lengths are easier to compare.
- As this answer shows, it's better to correctly use the plotting API, for either `seaborn` or `pandas`, to manage the legend.

  - `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend, and `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`.
- In this case, `df` already has labels to use for the legend.

  - If the dataframe does not have appropriate labels, it is better to manage, transform, and clean the dataframe, and let the plotting API deal with legends, labels, etc.

    - Use [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename columns and index values.
    - Use [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to add a new column to be used for `hue` in `seaborn`.
- See [Move seaborn plot legend to a different position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27019079/7758804) and [How to put the legend outside the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4700614/7758804) for a thorough exploration of the moving legends options.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.3`, `pandas 2.0.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample wide dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 5, 9],[3, 5, 7]]),
                  index=['Positive', 'Negative'])

# covert to long form
dfm = df.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index(names='Cat')
```

### Stacked bars with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

- This requires one line of code to implement.

```py
# transpose and plot the dataframe
ax = df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, figsize=(8, 6))

# cosmetics
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
ax.legend(title='Cat', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

- with `stacked=False`, which is the better option.

[image]

### Stacked bars with [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html)

- `seaborn` works best with data in a long form, so `dfm` is used.

  - `sns.barplot` does not do stacked bars, so `sns.histplot` must be used.
- `histplot` is for showing the distribution of continuous data, and since the column passed to the `x-axis` is numeric, the axis is presented as continuous, not discrete categories.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.histplot(data=dfm, x='variable', weights='value', hue='Cat', multiple='stack', discrete=True, ax=ax)

# cosmetics
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

### Grouped bars with `seaborn.barplot`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.barplot(data=dfm, x='variable', y='value', hue='Cat', ax=ax)

# cosmetics
ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)
```

[image]