# How to change position of legend in seaborn faceted grid plot

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, facet-grid

I'd like to move down the subtitles in order to generate less confusion.

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings(action='once')
from scipy import stats
import numpy

df = pd.read_csv("serieA.csv")
df['dxG'] = df['xG'] - df['xGA']
df['dG'] = df['GF'] - df['GA']
df.head()


#%%
sns.set_palette("husl")
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Squadra", hue="Venue", col_wrap=5, hue_order=["Home", "Away"]) 
g.map(sns.distplot, 'dxG', hist=False, kde=True, kde_kws={'kernel':'gau','shade':'True'} ).set_titles("{col_name}").add_legend()

for ax in g.axes:
    ax.title.set_position([0.5, 2])

plt.xlim(-6,6)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

Now I have this plot:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGmvn.png)

How can I move down the subtitles position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move seaborn plot legend to a different position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019079/move-seaborn-plot-legend-to-a-different-position)

Comment: The question you ask in the title differs from the one you ask at the end of the question. What do you want know now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the legend, then you can do it by specifying the legend position using the below code.

> Code:

```
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

This will move the legend to lower right position.
You can also choose any of the following as you want;

```
best
upper right
upper left
lower left
lower right
right
center left
center right
lower center
upper center
center
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well.
I'd like to edit the position of the name of each column, that is the team name (col='Squadra')