# Edit labels and move legend in seaborn

Tags: seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I have a seaborn scatterplot, which I want to change its labels and move the legend outside the graph. There are many solutions to fix each of the issues, but I cannot fix both of them simultaneously. Adapted from a solution in stackoverflow which was intended for `sns.lmplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, legend=False)

plt.legend(title='Smoker', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), labels=['Hell Yeh', 'Nah Bruh'])
plt.show(g)
```

Here `legend=False` and is defined later by matplotlib. The issue is the plot only displays the first label and not the rest in the legend.

I have tried another way to modify the label by `legend='full'` and later modifying it:

```
g = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, legend='full')

h,l = g.get_legend_handles_labels()
l = ['Smoking behaviors:','Hell Yeh', 'Nah Bruh']
g.legend(h, l)
```

but the command `g.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)`does not work properly and edited labels do not show up. Only original labels are shown.

So, I can fix both of these issues separately, but not at the same time.

Comment: Moving the legend should now be done with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849891/7758804) from `seaborn 0.11.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current version of Seaborn's scatterplot (0.11.1), you can first create the legend in full and afterwards change it by calling `ax.legend()` again.

Note that the return value of `sns.scatterplot` is an `ax` as it is an [axes-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions).  This should not be confused with figure level functions which return a complete grid of "axes" and often are written as `g = sns...`.

Different seaborn functions create legends in different ways. Depending on the options used, the legend can become quite intricate and not easy to change. Making legends easier to modify is planned in Seaborn's future developments.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, legend='full')
ax.legend(title='Smoker', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), labels=['Hell Yeh', 'Nah Bruh'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only issue is when I run the same code, in the legend section I don't see the blue circle representing the second category, as if it is white. I ran it with my own data and the same problem happened. May be there is something wrong with my seaborn. Its version is 0.10.

Comment: Seaborn changed a lot since version 0.10.  You can try to create a [custom legend from handles](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html)

Comment: Thanks :)
After updating, the problem is solved.