# How to move or remove the legend from a seaborn JointGrid or jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, jointplot, jointgrid

How to remove the legend in the [`seaborn.JoingGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html) plot?

The reference code is like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I have tried to use the following methods that are known to work on the other seaborn plots, but failed on the jointplot:

```
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
g._legend.remove()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To remove the legend, the correct part of the [`sns.JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html) must be accessed.

  - In this case `g.ax_joint` is where the legend is located.
- As stated in a comment by [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom), ***Matplotlib axes have `.legend` (a method that creates a legend) and `.legend_` (the resulting object). Don't access variables that start with an underscore (_legend), because it indicates they are private.***
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

  - `g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot, legend=False)` may be used instead.

### `sns.JointGrid`

```py
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)  # legend=False can be added instead
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)

# remove the legend from ax_joint
g.ax_joint.legend_.remove()
```

[image]

- Moving the `JointGrid` legend can be done with `sns.move_legend`, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849891/7758804).

  - This also requires using `g.ax_joint`.

```py
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)

# move the legend in ax_joint
sns.move_legend(g.ax_joint, "lower right", title='Species', frameon=False)
```

[image]

---

### With [`sns.jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html)

- `g.ax_joint.legend_.remove()` can be used, but removing the legend is more easily accomplished by passing `legend=False` to the plot: `sns.jointplot(..., legend=False)`.
- `g.ax_joint.` is still required to move the legend.

```py
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")  # legend=False can be added instead

# remove the legend
g.ax_joint.legend_.remove()

# or 

# move the legend
# sns.move_legend(g.ax_joint, "lower right", title='Species', frameon=False)
```