# How can I customize the legend with Seaborn 0.12 objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, seaborn-0.12.x

The new Seaborn objects (v 0.12) are great but I struggle to deal with legend customization. Especially when using matplotlib to define subplots. My code:

```
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(3.5, 3.5), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1.5,1]}, dpi=dpi)
(
     so.Plot(sert_neurons, x='mod_index_late', y='opto_mod_roc', color='sig_modulation')
     .add(so.Dot(pointsize=2))
     .add(so.Line(color='k'), so.PolyFit(order=1), color=None)
     .limit(x=[-1, 1], y=[-1, 1])
     .label(x='Spontaneous 5-HT modulation', y='Task evoked 5-TH modulation')
     .on(ax1)
     .plot()
)
plt.tight_layout()
sns.despine(trim=True)
```

[image: this figure]

The does not have any legend (it seems to be located outside of the plot limits). When I do something like

`ax1.legend(frameon=False, prop={'size': 5}, loc='upper left')` I get the message `No artists with labels found to put in legend.` How can I move the legend to within the subplot and customize it's appearance?

Answer (score 6):

Control over the legend position from within the Plot interface is still WIP but since you're using external `matplotlib` objects it's not that hard to transfer its contents:

```py
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

(
    so.Plot(tips, x='total_bill', y='tip', color='day')
    .add(so.Dot(pointsize=2))
    .add(so.Line(color='k'), so.PolyFit(order=1), color=None)
    .on(ax1)
    .plot()
)

legend = f.legends.pop(0)
ax1.legend(legend.legend_handles, [t.get_text() for t in legend.texts])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work fully for the marker + colour legend in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75935869/how-to-move-marker-and-color-sections-of-a-figure-legend - only the colour legend is accessible through the `matplotlib` handle.

Comment: The legend can be moved afterwards with the `seaborn` convenience function, `move_legend`: `sns.move_legend(ax2, "center right")`

Comment: See [How to move marker and color sections of a figure legend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75935869/21891079) for move marker + color legend