# How to move the legend position in the seaborn.objects API

Tags: python, seaborn, legend-properties, seaborn-0.12.x

I am using the new [`seaborn.objects`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html#objects-interface) API available in v0.12.0. None of the [examples](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#integrating-with-matplotlib) show how to move the legend position. For example, moving the legend to the bottom. Is there a way to do this?

Using [`sns.move_legend`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html), as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849891/7758804) results in a `TypeError`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

healthexp = sns.load_dataset('healthexp')

p = so.Plot(healthexp, "Year", "Spending_USD", color="Country")
p.add(so.Line())
sns.move_legend(p, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(.55, .45), title='Species')
```

### Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 p = so.Plot(healthexp, "Year", "Spending_USD", color="Country")
      2 p.add(so.Line())
----> 3 sns.move_legend(p, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(.55, .45), title='Species')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py:444, in move_legend(obj, loc, **kwargs)
    442 else:
    443     err = "`obj` must be a seaborn Grid or matplotlib Axes or Figure instance."
--> 444     raise TypeError(err)
    446 if old_legend is None:
    447     err = f"{obj} has no legend attached."

TypeError: `obj` must be a seaborn Grid or matplotlib Axes or Figure instance.
```

Comment: the comment by r-beginners unfortunately has nothing to do with the new `seaborn.objects` system

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633322/how-can-i-customize-the-legend-with-seaborn-0-12-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I customize the legend with Seaborn 0.12 objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633322/how-can-i-customize-the-legend-with-seaborn-0-12-objects)