# How do I use seaborn to combine violin plot, boxplot and lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have two groups of data, they are corresponding to each other. Now I want to make a violin plot, box plot, and a line plot connecting corresponding points.

It would go, from left to right, half-violin of group 1, box plot of group 1, line plot connecting group 1 and group 2, box plot of group 2, and then half-violin of group 2.

[image: Example plot with this setup]

This is from the article, ["Subspace partitioning in the human prefrontal cortex resolves cognitive interference"](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.2220523120)

I am using [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) for plotting. However, violin plot splitting always keep the left part of the plot in my attempts. Moreover, the boxplot, violin plot and line plot are stacked on top of one another.

How can I accomplish this using `seaborn`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Nice question! Could you provide code for what you have tried so far and what the result looks like? Additionally, providing some sample data to plot (or referencing a standard set of sample data that comes with `seaborn`) would make this an even better question. See [ask].

Comment: In my experience, `seaborn` may not be the best tool for this job. It's strengths are in providing a "grammar of graphics" approach of plotting on top of `matplotlib`. A high-level interface such as `seaborn` trades convenience and elegance for granular customizability. However, [creating the basic plot in `seaborn` and modifying the underlying `matplotlib` for customization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76865808/21891079) *may* work here.

Answer (score 0):

By using [this previous hack in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781988/13461740), you can easily define a function to split a violin plot:

```
def hack_violin(ax, side='left', color='blue'):
    for b in ax['bodies']:
        # get the center
        m = np.mean(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0])
        b.set_facecolor(color)
        # modify the paths to not go further right than the center
        if side == 'left':
            b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], -np.inf, m)
        else:
            b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], m, np.inf)
```

You will have to separate your violin plot in 2 independent plots, though. This is why I added an argument for the color of the plot. It keeps it homogenous. Here integrated to your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def hack_violin(ax, side='left', color='blue'):
    for b in ax['bodies']:
        # get the center
        m = np.mean(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0])
        b.set_facecolor(color)
        # modify the paths to not go further right than the center
        if side == 'left':
            b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], -np.inf, m)
        else:
            b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0] = np.clip(b.get_paths()[0].vertices[:, 0], m, np.inf)
            
# Generate some random data for two groups
group1_data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=100)
group2_data = np.random.normal(loc=2, scale=1.5, size=100)

# Create a figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Combine violin plot, box plot, and line plot
violin_left = ax.violinplot(group1_data, positions=[0.9], showmedians=False, showextrema=False, widths=0.1)
violin_right = ax.violinplot(group2_data, positions=[2.1], showmedians=False, showextrema=False, widths=0.1)

box = ax.boxplot([group1_data, group2_data], positions=[1, 2], patch_artist=True, widths=0.1, showfliers=False)
line = ax.plot([1.05, 1.95], np.array([group1_data, group2_data]), color='gray', lw=1, alpha=0.2)

hack_violin(violin_left, side='left')
hack_violin(violin_right, side='right')

# Customize the plot
ax.set_xticks([1, 2])
ax.set_xticklabels(['Group 1', 'Group 2'])
ax.set_ylabel('Value')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

And result:

[image: Split violins!]