# Legend obscures plot using Seaborn Objects API

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, seaborn-0.12.x

I have a recurring problem with legends on many of my plots with legends. The legend often obscures part of the data.

Reproducible example:

[image]

```
import seaborn.objects as so
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
res_df = pd.DataFrame(
 {'value': np.random.rand(20),
 'cfg__status_during_transmit': ['OK']*5 + ['ERR']*5 + ['WARN']*5 + ['OTH']*5}
)

(
    so.Plot(res_df, y='value', x='cfg__status_during_transmit', color='cfg__status_during_transmit')
    .add(so.Dots(), so.Jitter(width=0.5))
    .layout(size=(8, 4))
).show()
```

I've tried elongating the plot. This is a hack and isn't convenient, especially since it makes everything a lot smaller.

I've also tried plotting using `.on()` onto a `matplotlib` figure or axis, but the same problem persists. There's a related SO issue which advises that the legend properties are still in development. I would appreciate suggestions for how to get around this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want the legend? Outside the plot?

Comment: Yes outside, such that it doesn't overlap with the data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control over the legend using `seaborn.objects` might still be a work in progress according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633322/how-can-i-customize-the-legend-with-seaborn-0-12-objects). However, if I used `plot()` instead of `show()` I got a figure where the legend was placed outside the graph:

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
res_df = pd.DataFrame(
 {'value': np.random.rand(20),
 'cfg__status_during_transmit': ['OK']*5 + ['ERR']*5 + ['WARN']*5 + ['OTH']*5}
)

(so.Plot(res_df, y='value', x='cfg__status_during_transmit', color='cfg__status_during_transmit')
 .add(so.Dots(), so.Jitter(width=0.5))
 .layout(size=(8, 4))
).plot()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This works just as needed, many thanks. I found that starting the code block with `display`, i.e. `display( so.Plot(...` also works.