# seaborn legend (functions vs. object)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

when using seaborn functions I can get all handles and labels:

```
p=(
sns.scatterplot(data=peng, x='island', y='bill_length_mm', hue='species', style='sex')
)
print(type(p))
h, l = p.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(l)
```

> ['species', 'Adelie', 'Chinstrap', 'Gentoo', 'sex', 'Male', 'Female']

but when using seaborn object I get empty list:

```
p=(
so.Plot(data=peng, x='island', y='bill_length_mm', color='species',
        pointsize='species', fill='sex', marker='sex')
    .layout(size=(6,5))
    .add(so.Dots(stroke=0.5), so.Jitter(0.4))
    .scale(marker=["o", (6, 2, 1)], pointsize=(6,8), color='flare')
    .plot()
)

ax, = p._figure.axes
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(l)
```

> []

is there any method than can help in this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The seaborn objects API adds the legend(s) to the figure instead of the ax. You can loop over `p._legend_contents` to get to the handles labels:

```
p=(
so.Plot(data=peng, x='island', y='bill_length_mm', color='species',
        pointsize='species', fill='sex', marker='sex')
    .layout(size=(6,5))
    .add(so.Dots(stroke=0.5), so.Jitter(0.4))
    .scale(marker=["o", (6, 2, 1)], pointsize=(6,8), color='flare')
    .plot()
)

for key, artists, labels in p._legend_contents:
    print(f'{key[0]}: {labels}')
```

Output:

```
species: ['Adelie', 'Gentoo', 'Chinstrap']
sex: ['male', 'female']
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for :)
I tried to look for _legend_contents() in seaborn documentations, but I didn't find any result!

Comment: As the `_`-prefix suggests, `_legend_contents` is a private attribute, hence not documented. Support of advanced legend manipulations in the objects API seems to be rather limited. See this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73633322/how-can-i-customize-the-legend-with-seaborn-0-12-objects) for instance.