# How to plot daily data against a 24 hour axis (00:00 - 23:59:59)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, axis-labels, line-plot

I have a dataset with date_time, date, time, and a VALUE1 column that shows measurement values of each time point. For the same ID, there are multiple measurements over a day. Besides, there are 6 different 24 hour measurements for an ID, which is shown in INSPECTION column.

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day
# df['INSPECTION'] = df['INSPECTION'].replace(6, 1)
# df['INSPECTION'] = df['INSPECTION'].replace(3, 1)

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION'] == 1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2, 3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')

df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df.DATE_TIME.diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df['TIMEINTERVAL'].fillna(0)


def to_day_period(s):
    bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
    labels = ['Nighttime', 'Daytime', 'Daytime', 'Nighttime', 'Nighttime']

    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(s),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )


df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = to_day_period(df['TIME'])
df_monthly = df

# ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ sns plot ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
df_id = df[df.ID==1]
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(14,8)})
#print(df_id.INSPECTION.unique())
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df_id, x ='TIME', y = 'VALUE1',
                  hue='INSPECTION', palette='viridis',
                  legend='full', lw=3)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.ylabel('VALUE1')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I show a 24 hours day cycle on the x-axis without repeating the time again? To articulate, x-axis starts at 00:40:00 and then it shows 00:00:00 again. Is there a way to deal with this too? I want to show only time from 00:00:00 until 23:59:00 on the x-axis without repeating the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a column representing the total number of seconds for a given day, which will be used as the x-axis, and will ensure every point for a given `'INSPECTION'` is properly positioned.

  - Given a specific day, subtract the day at midnight from the current datetime, and use the [`.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) method.
  - `df.DATE_TIME.apply(lambda row: (row - row.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds())`
- Set ticks to be every hour.

  - `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.MultipleLocator(3600))`
- Create a list of every hour, which will be used as the labels. `['']` is for the last tick at `'00:00'` of the next day.

  - `hours = [dtime(i).strftime('%H:%M') for i in range(24)] + ['']`
- This can also be done with `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)`, but that's a cosmetic change that's not relevant to the question.

  - See [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) for additional details about plotting in subplots.
- A seaborn legend should be move with `sns.move_legend`, not `plt.legend`, as per [Move seaborn plot legend to a different position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849891/7758804).
- It is more consistent to stick with the object oriented interface using `ax`, the alias for [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.html), than to alternate between `ax` and `plt`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.0`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
from datetime import time as dtime

# given the existing dataframe with the DATE_TIME column as a datetime Dtype

# add a column for total seconds
df['total_seconds'] = df.DATE_TIME.apply(lambda row: (row - row.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds())

# iterate through each ID
for id_ in sorted(df.ID.unique()):
    
    # select the data for the given id_
    data = df[df.ID.eq(id_)]

    # create a figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

    # plot the data
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=data, x ='total_seconds', y = 'VALUE1', hue='INSPECTION', palette='viridis', legend='full')
    
    # set the title and labels
    ax.set(title=f'ID: {id_}', xlabel='TIME', ylabel='VALUE1')
    
    # move the legend
    sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

    # constrain the x-axis limits to the number of seconds in a day
    ax.set_xlim(0, 24*3600)

    # create labels for every hour in the day, and add an extra spot for the last tick position
    hours = [dtime(i).strftime('%H:%M') for i in range(24)] + ['']

    # create xticks at every hour
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.MultipleLocator(3600))
    
    # set the ticks and corresponding labels; cut off extra starting and ending ticks to match labels
    ax.set_xticks(ticks=ax.get_xticks()[1:-1], labels=hours, rotation=90)
    
    # remove spines
    ax.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
```

[image]

#### `df.head()`

```
            DATE_TIME  ID      VALUE1     VALUE2  INSPECTION MODE      TIME    TIMEINTERVAL  total_seconds TIME_OF_DAY
0 2022-11-01 00:00:00   2  145.003985  57.488269           1    A  00:00:00             NaT            0.0   Nighttime
1 2022-11-01 00:20:00   2  142.449613  75.888882           1    A  00:20:00 0 days 00:20:00         1200.0   Nighttime
2 2022-11-01 00:40:00   1  119.748681  70.052981           1    A  00:40:00 0 days 00:20:00         2400.0   Nighttime
3 2022-11-01 01:00:00   2  149.170848  69.793085           1    A  01:00:00 0 days 00:20:00         3600.0   Nighttime
4 2022-11-01 01:20:00   2  148.873049  56.777515           1    A  01:20:00 0 days 00:20:00         4800.0   Nighttime
```