# How to modify a legend with hatches

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

I have created a barplot with hatches with the code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

hatches = ['\\\\', '//']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))
sns.barplot(data=tips, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time")

# loop through days
for hues, hatch in zip(ax.containers, hatches):
    # set a different hatch for each time
    for hue in hues:
        hue.set_hatch(hatch)

# add legend with texture
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

And it outputs the following plot:

[image]

If I try to modify the legend to (a) add a title and (b) change the hue labels, the code breaks down, and I lose the color and hatches from the legend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

hatches = ['\\\\', '//']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,3))
sns.barplot(data=tips, x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time")

# loop through days
for hues, hatch in zip(ax.containers, hatches):
    # set a different hatch for each time
    for hue in hues:
        hue.set_hatch(hatch)

# add legend with texture
plt.legend(title='My Title', labels=['Lunch_1','Dinner_2'], loc=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So my questions is: How do I add a title and modify the labels without losing the color and hatches from the legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) with the signature `legend(handles, labels)` after retrieving the original ones with [`get_legend_handles_labels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html) :

```
handles, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

plt.legend(handles, ["Lunch_1", "Dinner_2"], title="My Title", loc=1)
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- It's a best practice to clean the data in a DataFrame prior to plotting, and analysis. As such, the easiest way to deal with legend labels/titles, and axis labels, is to clean associated columns.

  - Update the column name used for `hue` (the legend title), with [`.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) or [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) methods, and the categorical column values (the legend labels) with [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).
- [Move seaborn plot legend to a different position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27019079/7758804) shows how to move seaborn axes level legends with `plt.legend` ([implicit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface)), `ax.legend` ([explicit](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface)), and the preferred [`sns.move_legend`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html).

  - However, in this case, `plt.legend` or `ax.legend` must be used for the hatches to show up on the legend handles, which requires resetting the legend `title`.
  - Now the legend `labels` don't need to be updated, so it's not necessary to pass extracted `handles`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `pandas 2.0.1`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# change column names for better presentation of axis labels and titles
tips.columns = tips.columns.str.replace('_', ' ').str.title()

# change a specific column name
tips = tips.rename({'Time': 'Hobbit Meals', 'Day': 'Shire Days'}, axis=1)

# change values in the column to have a better value
tips['Hobbit Meals'] = tips['Hobbit Meals'].map({'Dinner': 'Supper', 'Lunch': 'Elevensies'})
tips['Shire Days'] = tips['Shire Days'].map({'Thur': 'Trewsday', 'Fri': 'Hevensday', 'Sat': 'Mersday', 'Sun': 'Highday'})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3))
sns.barplot(data=tips, x='Shire Days', y='Total Bill', hue='Hobbit Meals', ax=ax)

# loop through axes bar containers
for c, hatch in zip(ax.containers, ['\\\\', '//']):
    # iterate through each patch in the container
    for patch in c:
        patch.set_hatch(hatch)

# in order to have the hatches appear on the legend hanles, the lengend method must me called
ax.legend(title=tips.columns[5], bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

# remove the spines for some additionaly cosmetic changes
ax.spines[['right', 'top']].set_visible(False)
```

[image]