# How to change the figure size of a seaborn axes or figure level plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, figsize

How do I change the size of my image so it's suitable for printing?

For example, I'd like to use an A4 paper, whose dimensions are 11.7 inches by 8.27 inches in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

You need to create the matplotlib Figure and Axes objects ahead of time, specifying how big the figure is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn

import mylib

a4_dims = (11.7, 8.27)
df = mylib.load_data()
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
seaborn.violinplot(ax=ax, data=df, **violin_options)
```

Comment: this solution does not seem to work with the code that follows (different kind of plot).  Any ideas?  I assume "mylib" is just a library where you stored your data and is not needed in this code:  ` fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(12,6));   sns.jointplot(memoryPrice['price'], memoryPrice['Memory'])  `

Comment: This answer doesn't work in @TMWP's case because jointplot is a figure level method. See answer below.

Comment: this answer doesn't work with those plot types that don't accept ax as an input, for example `sns.lmplot()`

Comment: Plot size in seaborn should be set using the `height` and `aspect` parameters as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602446/2412831

Comment: @LeandroOrdonez that's not really applicable to axes-level function.

Answer (score 552):

You can also set figure size by passing dictionary to `rc` parameter with key `'figure.figsize'` in seaborn `set_theme` method (which replaces the `set` method, [deprecated in v0.11.0 (September 2020)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew/v0.11.0.html#theming))

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
```

Other alternative may be to use `figure.figsize` of `rcParams` to set figure size as below:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams

# figure size in inches
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 11.7,8.27
```

More details can be found in [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#matplotlib-rcparams)

Comment: Unlike other solutions, this solution doesn't assume a certain way of defining the plot. Thanks.

Comment: Note that when you call sns.set(), it defaults your figure styles to the sns default instead of the matplotlib default, for example your figures would then suddenly have a grey background with white grid – see here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html.

Also, this didn't have any effect on the size of my plot (a sns.pairplot).

Comment: Nor mine as a sns.boxplot

Comment: Thanks for that @Melissa. This made me realise I have to call `.set()` before `.set_style()`

Comment: Alas they both don't produce any plot in Jupyter Lab. `fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(20, 2)); 
a = sns.lineplot(ax=ax, x=..., y=...)` instead works as expected. I am always surprised when such parameters, that should be straightforward in seaborn because used very often, need to be set using "tricks".

Comment: Note that `sns.set()` (and `sns.set_style()`) have to precede the plot (and `sns.set_style()` has to precede `plt.subplots()`, if you go for this alternative).

Comment: Don't know how many times have I visited this question just to copy paste the line hahah. Mi figures are all (11.7,8.27)

Answer (score 271):

Note that if you are trying to pass to a "figure level" method in seaborn (for example `lmplot`, `catplot` / `factorplot`, `jointplot`) you can and should specify this within the arguments using `height` and `aspect`.

```
sns.catplot(data=df, x='xvar', y='yvar', 
    hue='hue_bar', height=8.27, aspect=11.7/8.27)
```

See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/488 and [Plotting with seaborn using the matplotlib object-oriented interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23969619/plotting-with-seaborn-using-the-matplotlib-object-oriented-interface) for more details on the fact that figure level methods do not obey axes specifications.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that correctly deals with sns plots that don't accept ax as an argument.

Comment: Note that height and aspect control the dimensions of a single "facet," i.e. a subplot. So this doesn't directly adjust the full figure dimensions.

Comment: See also [this official tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#specifying-figure-sizes)

Comment: Note: this applies to `relplot` too. Even when creating a figure ahead of time using `plt.figure(figsize=...)`, I still needed to specify `height`/`aspect` to get the dimensions to change. I prefer this much more than the `sns.set()` solution because I want different values for different plots.

Answer (score 157):

first import matplotlib and use it to set the size of the figure

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = sns.barplot(x="Word", y="Frequency", data=boxdata)
```

Answer (score 110):

You can set the context to be `poster` or manually set `fig_size`.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
n, p = 40, 8
d = np.random.normal(0, 2, (n, p))
d += np.log(np.arange(1, p + 1)) * -5 + 10


# plot
sns.set_style('ticks')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# the size of A4 paper
fig.set_size_inches(11.7, 8.27)
sns.violinplot(data=d, inner="points", ax=ax)    
sns.despine()

fig.savefig('example.png')
```

[image]

Comment: this answer doesn't work with those plot types that don't accept ax as an input, for example `sns.lmplot()`

Comment: To expand on Chris's answer, some seaborn plots generate composite figures with multiple axes, so they CAN'T take a single axis as an argument.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to plot a violinplot. I was able to change the size of the figure inline in a Jupiter lab notebook.

Answer (score 69):

This can be done using:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.kdeplot(data,shade=True)
```

Answer (score 64):

In addition to *elz* answer regarding "figure level" methods that return multi-plot grid objects it is possible to set the figure height and width explicitly (that is without using aspect ratio) using the following approach:

```
import seaborn as sns 

g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='xvar', y='yvar', hue='hue_bar')
g.fig.set_figwidth(8.27)
g.fig.set_figheight(11.7)
```

Comment: `set_figwidth` and `set_figheight` work well for grid objects. >>> import seaborn 
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
>>> tips = seaborn.load_dataset("tips")
>>> g = seaborn.FacetGrid(tips, col="time",  row="smoker")
>>> g = g.map(pyplot.hist, "total_bill")
>>> g.fig.set_figwidth(10)
>>> g.fig.set_figheight(10)

Comment: Perhaps the API changed, but for me it was g.figure.set_figwidth instead of g.fig.set_figwidth.  I'm using matplotlib version 3.1.0 and seaborn 0.9.0

Comment: works with seaborn version `0.11.1` - the other solutions on this page didn't work

Answer (score 32):

This shall also work.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns    

plt.figure(figsize=(15,16))
sns.countplot(data=yourdata, ...)
```

Answer (score 29):

For my plot (a sns factorplot) the proposed answer didn't works fine.

Thus I use

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(11.7, 8.27)
```

Just after the plot with seaborn (so no need to pass an ax to seaborn or to change the rc settings).

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me with a FacetGrid
```python
g = sns.FacetGrid(df.set_index('category'), col="id")

pyplot.gcf().set_size_inches(11.7, 8.27)

g.map(lambda data, color: data.plot.barh(color=color), "count")
```

Comment: Same here. It seems like `sns.FacetGrid` would set a figure size according to a calculated value (set by `height` and `aspect`) and changing the figure size directly after seaborn plotting will work. And other fine tuning of the plot can happen after changing the figure size

Answer (score 24):

- See [How to change the image size for seaborn.objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74326894/7758804) for a solution with the new [`seaborn.objects`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html) interface from `seaborn v0.12`, which is not the same as seaborn axes-level or figure-level plots.
- Adjusting the size of the plot depends if the plot is a **[figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html?highlight=tight_layout#figure-level-functions-own-their-figure)** plot like [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html), or an **[axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html?highlight=tight_layout#axes-level-functions-make-self-contained-plots)** plot like [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html). **This answer applies to any [figure or axes level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html?highlight=tight_layout#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) plots**.

  - See the the [seaborn API reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html)
- `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`, so seaborn works with matplotlib methods
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Imports and Data

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
df = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
```

### `sns.displot`

- The size of a figure-level plot can be adjusted with the `height` and/or `aspect` parameters
- Additionally, the `dpi` of the figure can be set by accessing the `fig` object and using `.set_dpi()`

```py
p = sns.displot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', stat='density', height=4, aspect=1.5)
p.fig.set_dpi(100)
```

- Without `p.fig.set_dpi(100)`

[image]

- With `p.fig.set_dpi(100)`

[image]

### `sns.histplot`

- The size of an axes-level plot can be adjusted with `figsize` and/or `dpi`

```
# create figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 5), dpi=100)

# plot to the existing fig, by using ax=ax
p = sns.histplot(data=df, x='flipper_length_mm', stat='density', ax=ax)
```

- Without `dpi=100`

[image]

- With `dpi=100`

[image]

Answer (score 15):

```
# Sets the figure size temporarily but has to be set again the next plot
plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))

sns.barplot(x=housing.ocean_proximity, y=housing.median_house_value)
plt.show()
```

[image: An 18x18 plot of my graph]

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(X,Y))` does nothing, at least with the Jupyter extension in VS Code and  seaborn 0.12.2

Answer (score 10):

Some tried out ways:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15,7])
sns.boxplot(x="feature1", y="feature2",data=df, ax=ax) # where df would be your dataframe
```

**or**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=[15,7])
sns.boxplot(x="feature1", y="feature2",data=df) # where df would be your dataframe
```

Answer (score 9):

The top answers by Paul H and J. Li do not work for all types of seaborn figures. For the `FacetGrid` type (for instance `sns.lmplot()`), use the `size` and `aspect` parameter.

`Size` changes both the height and width, maintaining the aspect ratio.

`Aspect` only changes the width, keeping the height constant.

You can always get your desired size by playing with these two parameters.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28765059/3901029

Answer (score 0):

### Change Axes-level plot size

Seaborn has plotter functions that return Axes objects. The size of those plots can be changed globally using the `set()` or `set_theme()` functions (as given in [niraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47955814/19123103)).

```py
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.set_theme(rc={'figure.figsize': (8.27, 11.7)})
ax = sns.regplot(df, x='total_bill', y='tip')
```

The size of these plots can also be changed by changing the size of the underlying matplotlib figure that contains this Axes using `set_size_inches()`. Note that [dmainz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56970556/19123103)'s answer does a similar thing but it works by setting the width and height separately; this method sets them both in one function call. This is especially useful if your seaborn plot is created somewhere else and you want to change its size to whatever you want in inches.

```py
ax = sns.regplot(df, x='total_bill', y='tip')     # the default figsize is 6.4"x4.8"
ax.figure.set_size_inches(8.27, 11.7)             # now it becomes 8.27"x11.7"
```

If your seaborn plot is generated by the function that doesn't return a value, then you can still change it by accessing the current figure object using `plt.gcf()`. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.regplot(df, x='total_bill', y='tip')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8.27, 11.7)
```

Note that `set()` or `set_theme()` changes the figure size globally which may not be desirable if you only want to set a specific size of a single figure and use the default settings for others. In that case, you can use a context manager to change the figsize of a single figure.

```py
with plt.rc_context(rc={'figure.figsize': (8.27, 11.7)}):
    sns.regplot(df, x='total_bill', y='tip')
```

### Change figure / FacetGrid size

Similar to above where the underlying matplotlib figure size was changed, the same can be done for FacetGrid objects as well. A demo goes as follows:

```py
g = sns.lmplot(data=df, x='total_bill', y='tip')  # the default figsize is 5"x5"
g.fig.set_size_inches(8.27, 11.7)                 # now it becomes 8.27"x11.7"
```

Note that if your seaborn figure is generated by the function that doesn't return a value, then you can still change it by accessing the current figure object using `plt.gcf()`:

```py
sns.lmplot(data=df, x='total_bill', y='tip')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8.27, 11.7)
```

Comment: The proposed method seems to be the same as  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725768/7758804 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597200/7758804

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney fair enough, especially the first one seems to use this method the way I intended to use here. I probably should remove the part in my answer that has the same code (or at least add link to that answer). Tbf, I hadn’t seen these answers before I posted mine (that’s my fault) but I still feel my answer better explains the different ways it could be useful. Also, I show different ways to access the figure in order to set its size (as well as the context manager) which could be useful in this context.