# How to Change Figure Plot Size using Seaborn Package FacetGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, figure

I am making a plot using seaborn FacetGrid with dataframe: df. 
I am using sns because of the hue functionality.

See code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

grid = sns.FacetGrid(df,hue='var')
grid.map(plt.scatter, x, y).add_legend()
grid.set(ylim=ylim,xlim=xlim)
plt.show()
```

Normally I would access the figsize by using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
```

or

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
```

But now, because I'm using seaborn, I don't know how to access the figure-object.

How do I access the figure object in order to change the size of the plot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot might help you EDIT: I realise you may also be looking for aspect and size within Seaborn for each facet: 
size : scalar, optional

Height (in inches) of each facet. See also: aspect.

aspect : scalar, optional

Aspect ratio of each facet, so that aspect * size gives the width of each facet in inches.

Comment: Tnx Anne! using  size and aspect allowed me to change the size of the figure. 
However, I am still interested in how to access the figure object when deploying a graph using SeaBorn. Any idea?

Comment: Point taken. You can use some functions (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/seaborn-python-tutorial#figsize) but I have yet to see a function that really returns the figure-object. I am curious to see whether someone else knows a way to do that.

Comment: I cannot post an answer, so here we go:
In your example, the matplotlib Figure object will be `grid.fig`

Comment: You can also use arguments in FacetGrid like height. Example:
```sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="x", hue="category", height=15)```