# sns.relplot change figure size

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

How do I change the figure size and the style of sns.relplot?

I wrote:

```
## Load in packages

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white") #change style
sns.set_palette('viridis')
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,16)}) # change default figure size
import os
import statsmodels.api as sm
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

## Set working directory
os.chdir('/users/alissaswartz/documents/personal/cj affiliate interview')

## Import data 
df = pd.read_csv('cj_affiliate_dataset.csv',low_memory= False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.head()

## Pairplots: Clicks by Sales, Sales Amount in USD 
sns.relplot(x="clicks", y="sales",  ci="sd", hue='sale_amount_usd',palette="viridis",data=df)
plt.show()
```

I'm still getting the default figsize and style:

[image: sns.relplot example]

What do I need to change? I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602446/4124317) to the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect.