# Is there a restriction on catplot with subplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, categorical-data, subplot

Seaborn's catplot does not seem to be able to work with plt.subplots(). Am not sure whats the issue here but i dont seem to be able to put them side by side.

```
#Graph 1
plt.subplot(121)
sns.catplot(x="HouseStyle",y="SalePrice",data=df,kind="swarm")

#Graph 2
plt.subplot(122)
sns.catplot(x="LandContour",y="SalePrice",data=df,kind="swarm")
```

Output:
[image: Weird no output]
[image: Weird no output2]
[image: Finally output]

Comment: The accepted answer no longer works with current versions of seaborn because figure-level functions do not have an axes/ax parameter. Additionally, the other answers are already covered by the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the created axis to seaborn's `catplot` while plotting. Following is a sample answer demonstrating this. A couple of things

- I would suggest using `add_subplot` to create subplots like yours
- The `catplot` will still return an axis object which can be closed using `plt.close()` where the number inside the brackets correspond to the figure count. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088824/4932316) for more details on `close()`

---

**Complete reproducible answer**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, ax=ax1) # pass ax1

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, ax=ax2) # pass ax2

plt.close(2)
plt.close(3)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to work with placing axes in a catplot because I get this error: `UserWarning: catplot is a figure-level function and does not accept target axes.`

Comment: @Pherdindy, this is correct and I have not been able to find a solution. I also cannot simply use `plt.figure()` to make a new figure for `sns.catplot` to use, catplot always makes its own.

Comment: Note that since seaborn 0.11, `catplot` (and similar figure-level functions) don't accept the `ax=` parameter anymore.  You either need to directly call the underlying axes-level function (e.g. `stripplot(...., ax=...)`) or convert the dataframe to "long form" (via pandas `melt`).

Comment: produces two blank plots for me.

Answer (score 7):

Catplot is a figure-level function whereas you cannot use axes. Try using **stripplot** instead.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots (1, 2, figsize=(25, 15))
sns.stripplot(x='category_col', y='y_col_1', data=df, ax=axs[0])
sns.stripplot(x='category_col', y='y_col_2', data=df, ax=axs[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sheldore for giving an idea of using close(). I tried this way and it worked.

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(20,10))
for n, feat in enumerate(cat_feats):
        sns.catplot(x='feat', kind='count', data=df, ax=ax[n//3][n%3])
        plt.close()
```