# Why did the plotting drop down? (Seaborn, Python)

Tags: python, seaborn

```
f, ax=plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,6))

sns.barplot('Parch','Survived', data=data, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Parch vs Survived')

sns.factorplot('Parch','Survived', data=data, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('Parch vs Survived')

plt.show()
```

As a result, the `frist_plot` goes well but the second plotting is separated and drops down.I add the `result_image` for illustration:
[image]

Why is the second sns.plot separated to down, and what do I have to do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, make sure to create a title for the question that responds to your problem. In your case it would be: `sns creates an empty graph when using barplot and factorplot in plt.subplots`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
f, ax=plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,6))
sns.barplot('parch','survived', data=data, ax=ax[0])
sns.factorplot('parch','survived', data=data, ax=ax[1])
plt.close(2)
plt.close(3)
```

[image]

[Here you can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959764/seaborn-factorplot-generates-extra-empty-plots-below-actual-plot) more information on why this is happening.

Comment: OMG, you know I'm in titanic_Kaggle!! Thank U so much and I solved it in VScode.  but kaggle jupyter is still. I think kaggle jupyter is dumb