# How to set figure size in lmplot seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, lmplot, figsize

My attempts to set figure size in lmplot have failed and therefore I would welcome your advice.

My code:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(18,16)})

sns.lmplot(x = 'index', y = 'values', data = data.reset_index(), hue = 'data' )
```

The plot that is produced below ignores the figure settings:

[image]

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602446/4124317) of the ducplicate