# How do I change the plot size for a seaborn scatter plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have probably tried all the [solutions presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot), but none works.

How to increase the size of a scatter plot using Seaborn? And why does it have to be so complicated

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8)) 
scatter_preco_area = sns.relplot(data = apartamentos,
                                 x = "Area", y = "Preco").set(title = "Relação entre área e preço")
```

Returns this (ignoring the figsize):

[image]

And this one:

```
scatter_preco_area = sns.relplot(data = apartamentos,
                                 x = "Area", y = "Preco").set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
```

Returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no property 'rc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height` and `aspect` arguments could be used to change plot size.
This code may works:

```
sns.relplot(data = apartamentos, x = "Area", y = "Preco",
            height = 8, aspect = 1.25)
```

Comment: it works! And after dozens of failed attempts the chart finally has the size I want!!! I have no idea why nothing else worked, but who cares??? Thank YOU!!!