# How can we change the size of all Seaborn plots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm working, in a Jupyter Notebook, with a dataframe that's pretty large. Here is a tiny sample of what I'm dealing with.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':7000, 'Revenue':5000, 'Building':'Stadium'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':3000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Stadium'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Casino'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Casino'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'School'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'School'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'School'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'School'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Hospital'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Hospital'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Hospital'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Hospital'},
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':6000, 'Building':'Arena'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':4000, 'Building':'Arena'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'Revenue':9000, 'Building':'Arena'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':6000, 'Revenue':10000, 'Building':'Arena'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

I received some great advice from people yesterday, on how to plot this.

```
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Month', 'Building'], value_vars=['Expense', 'Revenue'])
sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=dfm, x='Month', y='value', hue='variable', col='Building')
plt.show()
```

Now, this works, but everything is so tiny, I can't even tell what's what.

[image]

I tried three ways to try to increase the size of each graph.

1)

```
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(15,8)})
```

2. 

```
p = sns.lineplot(data = df)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15, 8)
```

3. 

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15,8
p = sns.lineplot(data = df)
```

None of these code samples did anything to change the size of any plot. Has anyone here encountered this before? Any thoughts on how to increase the size of each of these plots?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602446/9245853

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the size and aspect parameters of the seaborn plot.

Size changes the height, while maintaining the aspect ratio. Aspect changes the width while keeping the height constant.

Answer (score -1):

you have give the values to `height` and `aspect` parameters inside the `sns.catplot()` call.

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(10, 15)})

dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Month', 'Building'], value_vars=['Expense', 'Revenue'])
sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=dfm, x='Month', y='value', hue='variable', col='Building', height=15, aspect=10/15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to get it to work? Mine are too big though rather than too small.