# How to change boxplot size in seaborn FacetGrid object

Tags: python, boxplot, seaborn

I have a row of boxplots I produce using the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Column0", sharex=False)
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'column1', 'Column2')
```

It works well with the exception that the plots are super tiny. I have looked at [How can I change the font size using seaborn FacetGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328003/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-using-seaborn-facetgrid) and [How to change figuresize using seaborn factorplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163702/how-to-change-figuresize-using-seaborn-factorplot) as well as the seaborn manual, but I do not find the right way to include 'size' and 'aspect' into the code. What would be the proper way to change the plot size?

**EDIT**

If I try it like this:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Column0", sharex=False, size=20, aspect=3)
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'Column1', 'Column2')
```

I get the error: `ValueError: width and height must each be below 32768`. Is there a restriction in size for plots that are produced the way I do it?

Comment: Did you try setting `figsize = something` ?

Comment: Tried it in several ways, but did not get the desired results. My plots remain small. But maybe also because I did it wrong. what would be the appropriate way to built figsize into my code? This here `%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
figsize=(20, 16)
g = sns.FacetGrid(I, col="Origin", sharex=False)
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'Year', 'ResGeneCount')` changes nothing

Comment: what's `df['Column0'].unique().shape[0]`? sounds like you're trying to create a plot that's too wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try limiting maximum x and y values so that you plot will  automatically adjust to values that are important.

```
g.set(xlim=(0, 60), ylim=(0, 14));
```

you say that plot is super tiny that means there are some elements present with very high values.