# How to resize a seaborn catplot

Tags: python, seaborn

For resizing Seaborn figure-level plots, I've been following this convention:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
sns.catplot(x='xdata', y='ydata', data=df, kind='swarm', ax=ax)
```

This works for the catplot as well, however it generates a second, completely blank plot. Is this a bug in Seaborn (or am i doing something wrong)? Is there any way to properly resize this plot without getting a second blank plot (when i say blank plot i mean a plot with no data just same axis labels as the first plot)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443896/4124317).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider not calling `subplots` and use *height* and *aspect* arguments as this seaborn [factorplot solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28765059/1422451) shows where aspect is the width multiple of height, likely to keep dimensions consistent:

```
sns.catplot(x='xdata', y='ydata', data=df, kind='swarm', height=5, aspect=2)
```

From `help(sns.catplot)` output:

```
height : scalar, optional
        Height (in inches) of each facet. See also: ``aspect``.

aspect : scalar, optional
    Aspect ratio of each facet, so that ``aspect * height`` gives the width
    of each facet in inches.
```

To demonstrate with random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.sample(71318)
df = pd.DataFrame({'xdata': np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia', 'sas', 'spss', 'stata'], 100),
                   'ydata': np.random.choice(range(1,6), 100)})

sns.catplot(x='xdata', y='ydata', data=df, kind='swarm', height=5, aspect=2)

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Seaborn Plot Output]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. It seems so strange that sizing wasn't standardized throughout the library..