# plt.figure not resizing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, figsize

I have this function and I want to change the size of the figure, however whatever values I put in the figsize, the figure size does not change. Can anybody suggest what's the problem? or if there is an alternative way for doing this?

```
def plot_comparison_barplots(df, bar_col, hue_col, scaled):

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
    fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 9})
     
    ax = sns.catplot(x=bar_col, y='count in %', data=df, hue=hue_col, kind='bar', order=scaled)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data that would make your issue reproducible?

Comment: added the data, as an example

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to implement this function, by using `subplots` instead of `figure`, as when you use the `set_tight_layout()` method, this automatically changes the location of the axes to make your graph look nicer, and make sure that none of the axis names are cut off. The quickest way of getting around this is to define your axes before the `set_tight_layout()` method, so that the `figsize` parameter overrides it.

**Change**:

`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))`

to

`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,10))`

Comment: Thanks it does resize but it also generates together with my graph also an additional blank graph with standard size

Comment: Could you add an image of it to your question please, so that I could have a look?

Comment: Fund the solution to the blank figure here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826447/how-to-resize-a-catplot-of-kind-swarm-in-seaborn-without-generating-a-second-p catplot already generates a figure and it suggested not to use subplot. I can change the size of the figure using "height" and "aspects" in catplot directly

Answer (score 0):

You can add through Seaborn as:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(12,10)})
```